# SQL: How can I declare a variable inside a derived table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, left-join, declare, derived-table

I'm trying to create a comma separated list and I'm using a derived table. But I cannot declare the variable within the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`... how can I do this?

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (

               DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
               SELECT @String = COALESCE(@String + ', ','') + Name
                 FROM MyTable
               SELECT @String, Col1
                 FROM MyTable
                GROUP BY Col1

    ) AS T8
   ON This = That
```

It gives me an error on the `Declare` keyword that says, Incorrect Syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable inside a derived table.

But you may declare it outside of the statement and use it in the same way as you did in your example

Comment: I tried that and it underscores the "+ Name", giving the error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected.

Comment: which table has "Name" column?

Comment: No, there must be no problem: *SELECT @String = COALESCE(@String + ', ','') + Name FROM MyTable* must accummulate all the values from "Name" column. Try simply execute only this statement (with declaration of the string of course).

Comment: When executing `DECLARE @String AS VARHCAR(MAX) = NULL
SELECT @String = COALESCE(@String+', ','') + Name FROM MyTable`  it executes fine...

Comment: great! the next step is to add your computed string the the derived table:     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT @String, Col1
                 FROM MyTable
                GROUP BY Col1

    ) AS T8

Comment: that all works... I've moved it outside the Join and I think it'll work that way. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I'm not sure how that's going to work. Do you expect the same value for @String every time, or should it not be related to the Col1 value in the table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand according to the question author wanted to accummulate values from "Name" column and then use the same value with Col1 value.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` implies to me that each `Col1` value will have a different set of `Name` values. Maybe I'm wrong, and that's ok, but I don't see the point of including the exact same grouped concat value on every row of the result set. Why not just return that value as a separate single scalar value?

Comment: @AaronBertrand depends on what author wants to achieve. I am pretty sure that the statement may be more optimized, but the details were not specified. The question was stated, the answer is given.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yeah it's not working like I though since I moved it out. It looked fine until I started adding rows and then I saw how it was the same thing on every row of the result set. -- I'm trying to fix it now... sry ;/

Comment: @daveomcd did you try the approach that I posted? It's not going to be fast (especially as the 8th of who knows how many tables in the join) but it should give the expected results, which I assumed should be different on each row. I suggest you don't accept answers until you have proven that they're correct - then you don't have to disappoint people and take their rep away.

Comment: @daveomcd if you explain a bit more what you need, then we may come up with the solution

Comment: @daveomcd Is that you need to have for every Col1 its corresponding Name? And you may have for one value from Col1 several values of Name?

Comment: I read up on functions and simplified the whole thing with just using a function. I also got all my joins down to 2 ;)

Comment: @daveomcd congrats! simplification is exactly what one should do ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement doesn't make sense because the variable can't really be used inside the table variable. And if you want to use it after the table variable, it still doesn't make sense... do you expect multiple instances of the variable, once for each distinct value of Col1? Maybe you meant this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT Col1, String = STUFF((
     SELECT ',' + Name
        FROM dbo.MyTable AS i 
        WHERE i.Col1 = o.Col1 
        FOR XML PATH(''), 
        TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS o
  GROUP BY Col1
) AS T8
ON This = That
```

However, T8 kind of scares me a little. How many tables are already involved in this join?

Comment: I wont lie at the moment it is 8... would a better thing be to make a view and then go from there?

Comment: Not nearly enough information to answer that question. Maybe if you post your entire query as a separate question, including table structure, some sample data, and desired results, and ask for help making it more optimized. An 8-table join seems a little high to me for anything but an extremely DW-related star join.